# c++ 2 dimensional static array compatible with 2 dimensional dynamic pointer

Tags: c++

Is there a way to declare 2 dimensional static array which is compatible with the dynamic pointer (TYPE**) ?

```
char strs1[2][256] = { "String 1", "String 2" }; // Static
```

What I want is to assign it to

```
char **strs2 = strs1;
```

Well, I can do something like that:

```
std::array<std::array<char, 256>, 2> arr = {"String 1", "String 2"};
char *temp[2] = { (char*)&arr[0], (char*) &arr[1] };
char **strs = (char**)temp;

cout << strs[0] << endl;
cout << strs[1] << endl;

// Output
String 1
String 2
```

But is there a better and simpler way to achieve the same result ?

Answer (score 1):

char** can never be a way to reference a an array of arrays (there are no two-dimensional arrays in C/C++) because it doesn't have the information on the inner array size. In particular, there is no way compiler can generate a proper access code in following snippet:

```
char** arr = initialize_by_hack();
arr[2][4] = '42';
```

Here, to calculate second offset (4) compiler needs to know the size of element array - but is is nowhere in the code and not available.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot change the fact that a two-dimensional array is incompatible with a `T**`.

You can only perform hacky workarounds like the one you posit in your question, or remedy the mistake or design flaw that initially led you to the requirement.

Since you're writing C++: why not use proper, modern, type-safe technologies rather than native arrays and a mess of pointers? A simple `Matrix<T,W,H>` class template that wraps a statically allocated `T[W*H]` but exposes two-dimensional indexing would be nice. Then just pass it around by reference (or, if you really must, by pointer).

Comment: If it was a new project I would never do that. But I have to do a maintenance of a 20+ years old code (very big code base) with the interfaces of the type `char**`. Allocating on the heap for the small temporary 2 dim strings leads to a lot of memory leaks and I want to avoid it.

Comment: @AlexandreA.: Unless it's a design bug, I find it unlikely that a library accepting `char**` into a function intends for you to pass two-dimensional array data in, simply because that's never made sense. I don't suppose you can give me more information about the interface in order to suggest a better remedy? I realise it's unlikely that you can.

Comment: These are not a library interfaces but the application internal ones. At some point someone decided that he wants to pass 2 strings as 2 dim array everywhere (probably just to have one parameter less :( ).

Comment: There are no two dimensional arrays in what you just described. It is a single-dimensional array of pointers (with two elements in it).